# How would you test responsive logic in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, responsive-design, jestjs, media-queries, e2e-testing

I am writing a custom React hook which has the following logic (simplified a bit):

```js
function useResponsive<T>(options: Array<[string, T]>) {
  for (const [mediaQuery, result] of options)
    if (window.matchMedia(mediaQuery).matches) return result

  return undefined
}
```

Now I'm testing this by mocking `window.matchMedia` before each test case like this:

```js
// simulate small screen window
window.matchMedia = mediaQuery => ({matches: mediaQuery === '(min-width: 320px)'}) // small screen
// run test then undo mocking

// simulate medium screen window
window.matchMedia = mediaQuery => ({matches: mediaQuery === '(min-width: 480px)'})
// run test then undo mocking
```

I'm using Jest and JSDOM and `window.matchMedia` is not implemented there, JSDOM doesn't do the actual painting.

I'd like to test this end-to-end **without any mocks**, by just setting window dimensions, in order to be sure my `useResponsive` hook works as expected.

Should I pick some e2e testing library? Which is a simple one? Or, is there another option?

**Update:** [source code for my tests atm](https://github.com/amankkg/test-symmetrical-octo-sniffle/blob/6c34e6c2fc1a95313eff3bcdde849319ed1fa6a0/test/index.test.tsx#L8)

Comment: We typically use [Cypress](https://www.cypress.io/) for this kind of UX tests

Answer (score 1):

Here is the unit test solution:

`useResponsive.ts`:

```js
export default function useResponsive<T>(options: Array<[string, T]>) {
  for (const [mediaQuery, result] of options) {
    if (window.matchMedia(mediaQuery).matches) {
      return result;
    }
  }

  return undefined;
}
```

`useResponsive.spec.ts`:

```js
import useResponsive from './useResponsive';

describe('useResponsive', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });
  it('should match media', () => {
    const mMediaQueryList = [];
    window.matchMedia = jest.fn().mockReturnValueOnce({ matches: mMediaQueryList });
    const options: Array<[string, string]> = [['(min-width: 400px)', 'some result']];
    const actual = useResponsive(options);
    expect(actual).toBe('some result');
  });

  it('should not match media', () => {
    window.matchMedia = jest.fn().mockReturnValueOnce({ matches: undefined });
    const options: Array<[string, string]> = [['(min-width: 400px)', 'some result']];
    const actual = useResponsive(options);
    expect(actual).toBeUndefined();
  });
});
```

`jest.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest/presets/js-with-ts',
};
```

Unit test result with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/59448015/useResponsive.spec.ts
  useResponsive
    ✓ should match media (5ms)
    ✓ should not match media (2ms)

------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File              |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files         |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 useResponsive.ts |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.578s
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/59448015

Comment: Thanks for showing the right way of mocking in Jest! I will refactor my own unit tests. Initially, it was a take-home task with a tight deadline so I ignored Jest helpers to get things done.